# Error Unexpected formatting Networks edges exception. ValueError: not enough values to unpack. add_nodes_from() problem

Tags: python, numpy, graph, networkx

**Problem**

Batch processing with CSV files, nodes, edges. Need to create graph data and load netowrkx.from_csv().

Started adding nodes and edges to networkx graph using graph.add_nodes_from(_nodes) and graph.add_nodes_from(_edges). Nodes and edges are visible in sparse array. But code does not load properly.

When I execute *_nodes = [n for n in nodes]*, I get the same errors.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from sknetwork.data import from_edge_list, from_adjacency_list, from_graphml, from_csv
from sknetwork.visualization import svg_graph, svg_bigraph
from sknetwork.utils import bipartite2undirected

edges = from_csv("edges.csv")
nodes = from_csv("nodes.csv")

_nodes = [n for n in nodes]
_edges = [n for n in edges]

G = nx.Graph() 
G.add_nodes_from(_nodes) # see below error
G.add_edges_from(_edges) # see below error
print(nx.info(G))
```

**Multiple Paths Execution**

When I run *G.add_edges_from(_edges), this error is raised:

```
Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception
```

When I run *G.add_nodes_from(_nodes)*, this error is raised:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py:562, in Graph.add_nodes_from(self, nodes_for_adding, **attr)
    561 try:
--> 562     if n not in self._node:
    563         self._adj[n] = self.adjlist_inner_dict_factory()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'csr_matrix'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[99], line 10
      7 _labels = [n for n in edges][1:]
      9 G = nx.Graph() 
---> 10 G.add_nodes_from(_nodes) 
     11 G.add_edges_from(_edges) 
     12 print(nx.info(G))

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py:569, in Graph.add_nodes_from(self, nodes_for_adding, **attr)
    567         self._node[n].update(attr)
    568 except TypeError:
--> 569     nn, ndict = n
    570     if nn not in self._node:
    571         self._adj[nn] = self.adjlist_inner_dict_factory()

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

**Data**

```
print(nx.info(G))
_nodes

[<1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 385 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5077 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2833 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5795 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
```

```
_edges

[<1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 248 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 241 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 241 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 246 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 246 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 254 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 254 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 240 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 240 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 246 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 246 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 210 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 203 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 207 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 187 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 243 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 243 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 208 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 208 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
```

**Sample Data nodes**

```
(0, 1265)   1
  (0, 1338) 1
  (0, 1413) 1
  (0, 1643) 1
  (0, 1719) 1
  (0, 1806) 1
  (0, 2052) 1
  (0, 2128) 1
  (0, 2641) 1
  (0, 2872) 1
  (0, 3100) 1
  (0, 3244) 1
  : :
  (5778, 52)    1
  (5779, 3) 4
  (5780, 3) 4
  (5781, 1) 1
  (5781, 3) 2
  (5781, 29)    1
  (5782, 3) 4
  (5783, 3) 4
  (5784, 3) 4
  (5785, 3) 4
  (5786, 3) 4
  (5787, 3) 4
  (5788, 3) 2
  (5788, 5) 1
  (5788, 47)    1
  (5789, 3) 4
  (5790, 3) 2
  (5790, 5) 1
  (5790, 47)    1
  (5791, 3) 4
  (5792, 3) 2
  (5792, 5) 1
  (5792, 29)    1
```

**Sample Data edges**

```
(0, 682)    1
  (0, 683)  1
  (0, 755)  1
  (0, 756)  1
  (0, 794)  1
  (0, 807)  1
  (0, 808)  1
  (0, 883)  1
  (0, 884)  1
  (0, 965)  1
  : :
  (5793, 1492)  1
  (5793, 1968)  1
  (5793, 2050)  1
  (5793, 2347)  1
  (5793, 2491)  1
  (5793, 3171)  1
  (5793, 3549)  1
  (5793, 3772)  1
  (5793, 5469)  1
  (5793, 5504)  1
  (5793, 5727)  1
  (5793, 5766)  1
  (5793, 5767)  1
  (5793, 5768)  1
  (5793, 5769)  1
```

Comment: When you do `print(nx.info(G))`, is that just after `G = nx.Graph()`?  I don't know anything about `nx` or `sknetwork`, but the display of `_nodes` as a list of 1 row CSR matrices looks suspicious.  What does `edges` look like?  You need to spend more time with the documentation of those packages.

Comment: Why are you doing `[n for n in nodes][1:]`?  Is there some documentation that tells you to do that?  I see from https://scikit-network.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/data.html?highlight=from_csv#sknetwork.data.from_csv that `edges` and `nodes` are sparse matrices.  I can't think of a reason to split them up into lists.

Comment: When I execute _nodes = [n for n in nodes], I get the same errors, the issue is how to get a cvs file of nodes and edges to load into networkx. These nodes and edges came from an extract of a graph database, so they are valid, just need to reconstruct.

Comment: edges appears to be a <1x5794 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 241 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Comment: I'm not asking about the `[1:]` part.  That just drops the first item (a sparse matrix itself?) from the list.

Comment: OK=Just seeking how to to load Graph networkx graph database using networkx on this graph to load these CSV nodes and edges